# Html in Razor MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I  write this in MVC 3 Razor correctly?

```
<li  <%if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "Home"){%> class="active"<%} %>><a href="@Url.Action("index", "Home")">Home</a></li>
```

Blessings

EDIT

this is my code and does not work :(

```
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
   <div class="container">
    <a class="brand" href="#">CYSAC 2.0</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "Home" ? "class=\"active\"" : string.Empty)><a href="@Url.Action("index", "Home")">Inicio</a></li>
            <li @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "University" ? "class=\"active\"" : string.Empty)><a href="@Url.Action("index", "University")">University</a></li>
            <li @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "Estudent" ? "class=\"active\"" : string.Empty)><a href="@Url.Action("index", "Estudent")">Estudent</a></li>

        </ul>
  </div>
 </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

please help

Comment: @kalu - define "doesn't work", and have you looked at the output HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
<li class="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "Home" ? "active" : """>
    <a href="@Url.Action("index", "Home")">Home</a>
</li>
```

This has a drawback of having an class="" if it's not the current controller, but in the newest version of Razor, it will recognize this and strip it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@(expression)` - syntax:

```
<li class="@((ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "Home" ?
           "active" : string.Empty)">
    <a href="@Url.Action("index", "Home")">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Fixed my answer, which is now almost identical to Mystere Man's and comes with the same disadvantage. However, without the parentheses the code doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found myself in the same situation  ( 5 months later ).

1) Define variable controllerName and set with controller name .ToLower()

2) Compare with Equals("home")

```
    @{ 
        var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToLower(); 
    }
    <div class="navbar">
     <div class="navbar-inner">
       <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="#">CYSAC 2.0</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="@(controllerName.Equals("home") ? "active" : "")"><a href="@Url.Action("index", "Home")">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="@(controllerName.Equals("university") ? "active" : "")"><a href="@Url.Action("index", "University")">University</a></li>
                <li class="@(controllerName.Equals("estudent") ? "active" : "")"><a href="@Url.Action("index", "Estudent")">Estudent</a></li>

            </ul>
      </div>
     </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Works for me!